# How to load thumbnail for video?

Tags: android, thumbnails, picasso

I am trying to use `Picasso` to load video thumbnails, Unfortunately nothing seems to happen the imageview stays blank.

## code

```
VideoRequestHandler videoRequestHandler;
Picasso picassoInstance;
videoRequestHandler = new VideoRequestHandler();
picassoInstance = new Picasso.Builder(context.getApplicationContext())
  .addRequestHandler(videoRequestHandler)
  .build();

String fileName = "android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.default_video;
holder.searchVideoViewItem.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));                                                                      
picassoInstance.load(videoRequestHandler.SCHEME_VIDEO+":"+fileName).into(holder.searchVideoViewItemThumb);
```

---

## PicassoVideoFrameRequestHandler

```
public class PicassoVideoFrameRequestHandler extends RequestHandler {
    public String SCHEME_VIDEO="video";
    @Override
    public boolean canHandleRequest(Request data)
    {
        String scheme = data.uri.getScheme();
        return (SCHEME_VIDEO.equals(scheme));
    }

    @Override
    public Result load(Request data, int arg1) throws IOException
    {
        Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(data.uri.getPath(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        return new Result(bm, Picasso.LoadedFrom.DISK);  
    }

}
```

---

## Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_blue"
        android:id="@+id/searchVideolayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchImageViewItem">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/searchVideoViewItem"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/searchVideoThumbViewItem"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

            />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/success"
        android:id="@+id/searchVideoPlay"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If I am understanding your code correctly, `data.uri.getPath()` will actually be something with an `android.resource` scheme and therefore will not be referencing a video. FWIW, [here is a sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Media/VideoList) using Universal Image Loader to load the video thumbnails.

Comment: I am pulling a drawable from the app itself for testing.

Comment: `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()` isn't going to know how to load a drawable resource.

Comment: so is there a way to do a check and if it is a drawable resource how  doI load it then

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just load the video thumbnails? I mean, I just handed you a full project with source code to do just that. You're certainly welcome to examine what is being passed in the `Request` and make decisions about that, but if I were in your shoes, I would get rid of the resource stuff and *just load the thumbnails*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write your own class based on ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()

Create an instance of [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html), set data source as your content URI, then `getFrameAtTime(1000)` to get a frame for example at 1 second. This will give you a bitmap. Make sure you release the retriever!

Once you have a bitmap, calculate destination width and height (you can use this [example in docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)), then do

```
bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,dstWidth, dstHeight, ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
```

Also I suggest you do all this inside an AsyncTask as working with bitmaps is slow. [A good example is again in the docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)